# syntax error, unexpected in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax-error

In my controller: I got an error at this line  `@user_communication=User.where(:UserID = current_user.id)`. My method is given below.

```
 def new
    @user_basic=User.find(current_user.id)
    @students=Students.all
    @entrepreneurs=Entrepreneurs.all
    @veterans=Veterans.all
    @user_communication=User.where(:UserID = current_user.id)  
  end
```

And the error I got is given below:

```
C:/Sites/MentorMentored1/app/controllers/settings_controller.rb:21: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')' @user_communication=User.where(:UserID = current_user.id)
C:/Sites/MentorMentored1/app/controllers/settings_controller.rb:21: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end @user_communication=User.where(:UserID = current_user.id)
C:/Sites/MentorMentored1/app/controllers/settings_controller.rb:27: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end
```

I don't understand where is the syntax error, Kindly help me. Thanks

Comment: It should be `:UserID => current_user.id` (or `UserID: current_user.id`). BTW why didn't you accept an answer for any of your seventeen questions?

Answer (score 1):

Change your last line to:

```
@user_communication = User.where(UserID: current_user.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your AREL Statement expects a hash for the ´where´ condition.
Also, while not an error, it seems you are using CamelCase for your attributes. Ruby/Rails common practice is snake_case. You might want to change that in your model/db as well (again, this is not necessary for the code to work)

Use either of these syntaxes then:

```
User.where(:user_id => current_user.id)

User.where(user_id: current_user.id)
```